# Why is the filter not working in views.py?

Tags: python, django, post, frame, blogs

I'm trying to inject a query into an html with django, but the thing is that it saves to the database but the query doesn't recognize it, I will mention the relevant parts so you can see to what I'm referring.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from .forms import  PostForm, PostUpdateForm
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Post, Category



# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'app1/index.html')

class PostView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'app1/post.html'
    ordering = ['-post_date']

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(PostView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        return context

def CategoryView(request, cats):
    category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=cats.replace('-', ' '))
    return render(request, 'app1/categories.html', {'cats':cats.title().replace('-', ' '), 'category_posts': category_posts})

def CategoryListView(request):
    cat_menu_list = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'app1/category_list.html', {"cat_menu_list":cat_menu_list})

class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'app1/article_details.html'

class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'app1/createpost.html'
    #fields = '__all__'
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(AddPostView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        return context

class UpdatePostView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostUpdateForm
    template_name = 'app1/update_post.html'

class DeletePostView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'app1/delete_post.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

class AddCategoryView(CreateView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'app1/add_category.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('app1:Post')
```

In views the main problem is in the CategoryView function, specifically in the category_posts variable

```
{% extends "app1/base.html" %}
{% block body_block %}

{{category_posts}}

{% if category_posts%}

    <h1> {{cats}} Category</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for post in category_posts %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'app1:article-detail' post.pk %}">{{post.title}}</a> -
        {{post.author}} - <small>{{post.post_date}}</small> - 
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <small><a href="{% url 'app1:updatepost' post.pk %}">Edit</a></small><small>
        <a href="{% url 'app1:deletepost' post.pk %}">- Delete</a>  
        </small></li>
        {% endif %}
        {{post.body|slice:":200"|safe}} 

    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
<h1>Sorry this page does not exist</h1>
{% endif %}

    {% endblock %}
```

here is the problem, it is reading as false the if statement, and it is supposed to be true because it is in the data base.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from datetime import datetime, date
# Create your models here.


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 255)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index')
        
    

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('app1:article-detail', args=(self.id,))
```

I would really appreciate a lot your help, thanks for reading.

Comment: Well if the field is `foo bar`, and you filter with `bar-foo`, then it will not "match" that record.

Comment: Exactly with what query did you query this?

Comment: What is the category name you're trying to match and what url did you use to call the view?

Comment: the category is in models, in the post class

Comment: no idea why this isn't working

Comment: Why is `Post.category` a `CharField` and not a `ForeignKey` to `Category`?

Comment: And where are you passing `category_posts` to the template?

Comment: it's a charfield because it shows me this error if I put a foreignkey Django OperationalError: no such column

Comment: the queryset is just empty and I don't understand why